# Simple way to write XSLT for the XML listed

Tags: xslt

I have a complex xml. (only some part has been shown here). How simple my XSLT can be to display the following output.

Input XML

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>  <FINALDATA CPCreatedDate_UTC="2012-4-3 16:45:36.187">
> <SOLUTIONS>
>     <PROBLEMCAUSE Key="41607CD1-1B0F-45FA-B0DF-FACBCBBFCD19">thermocouple harness
>         <SOLUTION>
>             <ID>20600000000000000000000000000001</ID>
>             <MESSEAGE Key="1342F86E-6D34-429D-AE09-C71DB1933206">Broken wire</MESSEAGE>
>         </SOLUTION>
>     </PROBLEMCAUSE>
>     <PROBLEMCAUSE Key="7C6534BE-CEA5-4BD7-8C38-C2D51B72FA42">thermocouple data
>         <SOLUTION>
>             <ID>20600000000000000000000000000002</ID>
>             <MESSEAGE Key="DCA8E42A-BCD2-431F-87FA-9485F1B23C9E">Pump Value</MESSEAGE>
>         </SOLUTION>
>     </PROBLEMCAUSE>
>  </SOLUTIONS>
> </FINALDATA>
> ```

Output XML (Required)

> ```
> <Delta>
> <Package Time = "2012-4-3 16:45:36.187" >
>         <Entities>
>         <FailDatas>
>             <FailData>thermocouple harness</FailData>
>             <FailData>thermocouple data</FailData>  
>         </FailDatas>
>         <Messages>
>             <Message>Broken wire</Message>
>             <Message>Pump Value</Message>   
>         </Messages>
>     </Entities>
>     <Relationships>
>     </Relationships>
>     <Relationships></Relationships>
> </Package>
> </Delta>
> ```

All this i have to do based on the Key value listed above. Please help me in forming this.

Thanks
Ramm

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: In your output is `<Entities>` supposed to be a child of `<Package>`, or do you really want it as a sibling?

Comment: What do the `<Relationships>` elements in the output correspond to in the input?

Comment: What do you mean, *based on the Key value*, because I fail to see any relation?

Comment: Sorry Mads.. I missed out </Package>. It shoudl be at the last..

Comment: @mousio, i have to yet frame the relation part.. as the combinatin of PROBLEMCAUSE and MESSAGE key's will become a <Relation> for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="FINALDATA">
        <Delta>
                <Package Time="{@CPCreatedDate_UTC}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
               </Package>
        </Delta>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SOLUTIONS">
        <Entities>
            <FailDatas>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="PROBLEMCAUSE"/>
            </FailDatas>
            <Messages>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="PROBLEMCAUSE/SOLUTION/MESSEAGE"/>
            </Messages>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="PROBLEMCAUSE" mode="Relationships" />
        </Entities>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PROBLEMCAUSE">
        <FailData>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())"/>
        </FailData>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MESSEAGE">
        <Message>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </Message>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PROBLEMCAUSE" mode="Relationships">
        <Relationships />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```